# Exporting Oracle APEX regions with DBMS_LOB

Tags: html, plsql, blob, oracle-apex

I'm interested in exporting the contents of a page generated by Oracle-APEX to an external file while preserving as much formatting as possible. Eventually, I'd like to export it to either a .doc, .xls., or .pdf format. For now, I'm testing with a .doc file.

Currently, I'm attempting to do this by creating a PL/SQL anonymous block "Process" that executes when an "Export" button is pressed. Based off an example I found online, if I use the following code in the process, I can output one of the items in my page to a .doc file:

```
 DECLARE
    test_blob BLOB;

    BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(test_blob, FALSE);
   dbms_lob.open(test_blob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);

   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(test_blob, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(:P4016_ITEM_NAME));



   OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/doc', FALSE);
   HTP.p('Content-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.getlength(test_blob));
   htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "text.doc"');
   OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;
   WPG_DOCLOAD.download_file(test_blob);

    dbms_lob.close(test_blob);
END;
```

However, I would like to output some regions on my page that include tables, which are not considered items, as far as I know (I'm still very new to APEX). If I include the table name in the `DMS_LOB.APPEND` line, I receive an error message. Does anyone know of a simple way to reference these regions?

The only workaround I've found is to replicate the page in my exported file by enclosing the results of the SQL queries used to populate the tables in HTML based off the HTML of my APEX Page. In other words, if I wanted to italicize something, I would do the following:

```
...  
    dbms_lob.append(test_blob, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('<html><i>'));
    dbms_lob.append(test_blob, [PARSED SQL QUERY]);
    dbms_lob.append(test_blob, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('</i></html>'));
```

If anyone knows of a simpler way to do this, preferably involving a simple reference to my page regions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You've got a few problems here. (1) you want to get the generated HTML for a page, but Apex doesn't give you built-in access to this (perhaps some clever Javascript after the page is loaded might do the job); (2) you want to store a HTML page in a `.doc`, which I suspect may give strange results (MS Word will read html but might not deal with the CSS and javascript very well).

Comment: Assuming I were fine with using a .html file instead of .doc and I were able to get the JavaScript to work (or just copied the HTML from the "developer view" mode on my browser), do you think that this approach be feasible?

Comment: I think it's worth trying. I guess another alternative is to generate the page contents yourself in PL/SQL, which would then allow you to control where the contents are rendered/stored.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way (3 ways) to get PDF - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/custom-pdf-reports-1953918.pdf.
Also you can use Interactive report, it has export option. But it can be exported only in HTML by default.

It is not exactly what you ask, but you don't need to write code.

Comment: To your knowledge, do any of the three options outlined in that PDF require the end-users to download any additional software? It didn't look like it, at first glance, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: As I know, user don't have to install anything.